# Using Swift, I want to add information into a screen but after the first use I do not want to see it again

Tags: xcode, swift, storyboard, hidden

Ok so here is my question.

I want to have a screen pop up right after my LaunchScreen exits and i want to be able to add information into it, however once I add that information into it, I do not want to see that screen again.

I will be using storyboard, swift and CoreData and Xcode 6.3 if that helps.

Thanks in advanece

Comment: Well then don't segue back to it? xD This should be easy to figure out.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't help.  I want to go from my LaunchScreen.xib to the storyboard and input, into CoreData (I am fine with this part) and then move onto my NavigationController the first time the App runs.  After the information was saved into CoreData I want to go from my LaunchScreen.xib to my NavigationController, without seeing the info screen.

Comment: Oh I see, that wasn't clear to me. Could you just check to see if the CD has that type of data filled in?

Comment: Well thats the problem, not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

`NSUserDefaults` is a really quick way of storing (small amounts of) data.

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "hasSeenStartup")

if(defaults.boolForKey("hasSeenStartup")){
    println("Don't show")
}
```

First you will need to define a set of `userDefaults`, easiest is `standardUserDefaults()`
We can set a boolean value to a key (after we showed the popup screen) using `setBool()` this takes 2 parameters, the first is the boolean value, the second is a key for the value.

When the users launches the app, you will need to get the boolean value for the key. If the user already has seen the popup (it’s boolean value for `hasSeenStartup` will be set to true) you can skip the popup and show them the other viewController

EDIT:
Since your question seems to focus on showing the new view controller rather than saving the data. Here is some code on how to show a new view controller.

```
let storyboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc: NewViewControllerClass = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(“newViewController") as! NewViewControllerClass
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

To use this code you will need to change the:

1. Storyboard name to the name of your storyboard (defaults to “Main”)
2. Set the class of the viewController by replacing `NewViewControllerClass` with the class of (obviously) your new viewController.
3. Change the `newViewController` with the Identifier
   [image: change Identifier]

You can than use this code to present the new ViewController. Present this viewController if your Core Data has info saved about the user and thus if the user has seen the initial screen.

I would advice to retrieve the Core Data inside the `ViewDidAppear` method inside your `FirstViewController`.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if (check to see if core data is not empty){
        let storyboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc: NewViewControllerClass = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(“newViewController") as! NewViewControllerClass
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your still missing what I am trying to say (it's my fault).  Let me try again.  After the LaunchScreen, it goes to a VC called OnceViewController.  I need to input, into textfields, some personal info and then is able to save the information into CoreData.  I already have this part done.  Once the "save" button is pressed it goes onto another VC called ViewContoller.

What I need is when the app is started after the first time is that it checks the Core Data and sees the personal information is there to skip the FirstViewController and automatically show the ViewController.

Comment: @Scubadivingfool Edited my answer to include the answer to your question (at least I hope)

Comment: Something Like this?

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        if
            
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"MyEntity"];
        fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"rawData = nil"];
        NSArray *results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:0];

Comment: Sorry, totally confused on all this

Comment: Yes, after this but still inside the view did appear, you check to see if any items returned from the array, if !results.isempty{use the code above}